# Reply to an Azure Bot via Web Request - Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to reply to an Azure Bot via a Web Request, but everthing I try, even initiate a converstation, results in a `Authorization has been denied for this request.`

Using PowerShell, I run the following:

```
# Variables
$botServiceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/au/v3/conversations"
$botBody = '{}'
$clientID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$clientSecret = "This_is-a.Secret"
$headers = @{} 
$scope = "https://api.botframework.com/.default";
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$tokenBody = @{
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'  
    'client_id' = $clientID
    'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    'scope' = $scope
}
$tokenEndpoint  = {https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token} -f $tenantID

# Get Token
$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $tokenBody
    Method = 'POST'
    URI = $tokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

# Send message to Azure Bot
$headers.Add("Authorization","$($token.token_type) "+ " " + "$($token.access_token)")

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers = $headers
    Body = $botBody
    Method = 'POST'
    URI = $botServiceUrl
}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

Any help / suggestions, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - Found the issue.

I need to use the Uri `https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token` to retrieve a token specifically for Bots.

For example:

```
$clientID = ""
$clientSecret = ""
$recipientId = ""

# Get Token
$tokenEndpoint  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$tokenBody = @{
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'  
    'client_id' = $clientID
    'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    'scope' = "https://api.botframework.com/.default"
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{"Host" = "login.microsoftonline.com"}
    Body = $tokenBody
    Method = 'POST'
    URI = $tokenEndpoint
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

To start a conversation:

```
$conversationUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations"
$conversationBody = '{
    "bot": {
        "id": "28:'+$clientID+'",
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "29:'+$recipientId+'"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}'

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers = @{"Authorization" = "$($result.token_type) $($result.access_token)"  }
    Body = $conversationBody
    Method = 'POST'
    URI = $conversationUrl
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$conversationID = $result.id
```

I haven't worked out in PowerShell how to send a message yet, but I have the workflow in the Logic App working sending messages via HTTP Web Requests to the Bot in Teams.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that you have solved this issue, please accept it as answer to close this question and it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the root reason for it, but if you just want to have a communication with your bot using PowerShell Script, you can use [direct line 3.0 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to do so as a workaround.

Try command below:

```
$clientID = ""
$clientSecret = ""
$directLinekey = ""

$StartConversationUrl = "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations"

# Get Token
$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{"Authorization"="Bearer $directLinekey"  }
    Method = 'POST'
    URI = $StartConversationUrl
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$conversationID = $result.conversationId
$token = $result.token

# Send message to Azure Bot

$postMessageURL = "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/$conversationID/activities"
$botBody = @'
{
    "locale": "en-EN",
    "type":"message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text":"hello"
}
'@



$sendMessageParams = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers = @{"Authorization"="Bearer $token"}
    Method = 'POST'
    Body= $botBody
    URI = $postMessageURL
} 

$messageResult = Invoke-RestMethod @sendMessageParams 

$id= $messageResult.id

$getMessageURL = "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/$conversationID/activities"

$getMessageParams = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers = @{"Authorization"="Bearer $token"}
    Method = 'get'
    URI = $getMessageURL
} 

$allActs = Invoke-RestMethod @getMessageParams 

foreach($act in $allActs.activities){
    
    $act.from
    $act.text
    echo('-------')
}
```

Result on my side:

[image]

Comment: Yes - I have managed to use the Direct Line Channel successfully as well. The Uri I'm using is from the ServiceUrl parameter within the Activity of the message. I'm actually initiating a conversation from Teams to an Azure Bot. The Azure Bot then sends an HTTP Request to a Logic App. The Logic App responds to the Azure Bot, but I can only do this once. Then I try to send HTTP Request to the Bot using the ServiceUrl from the original message using a Bearer Token. This is when I receive the `Authorization has been denied for this request` error. Same result as per the PowerShell commands

Comment: @mrptsai,may I know what is your serviceURL?